# how to create an overlay effect with a color

Tags: html, css

I want to know how can I do a overlay but with a color in front. 
For example:

```css
.hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}

.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4  hover ">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250?text=IMAGEE" class="img-responsive " alt="Image">
</div>
```

it starts with some opacity, I want that opacity to be of  red on top of the image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rely on pseudo-element to create this overlay and then easily change the background using `rgba()` to obtain any color with any opacity:

```css
.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hover:hover::before {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="hover ">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250?text=IMAGEE" class="img-responsive " alt="Image">
</div>
```

Comment: is there  a way to decrease or increase the size of this background? for instance,  I am using col-sm-4, so it has some padding that I want to stay, How can I resize the  red background with the width and height already existing? @temani afif

Comment: @JoseAfonso simply control the top/left/right/bottom values :) make them bigger then 0 ;)

Comment: @JoseAfonso or make a container around your image like i did my code so you won't have to bother yourself with the bootstrap classes ;)

Comment: I forgot to put a measure there like px or %, that's why that wasnt responding me. After you said I fixed the padding for me.  @temani afif

Comment: what if there is text inside the box, is it possible to put that also transparent? like in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joseafonso123az/mf7jvry4/2/ @temani afif

Comment: @JoseAfonso yes you can use it above text, simply add z-index, i updated my answer with it as i forget it

Comment: thank you so much once again!   I have already upvoted and marked as the correct answer! @temani afif

Comment: Hi once again, Is it possible to create a link for the text inside the box? I used the <a> tag there, but when hovering cant get it as a link? jsfiddle.net/joseafonso123az/mf7jvry4/7

Comment: @JoseAfonso add `pointer-events: none;` to the before element

Comment: You are a life saviour! Can you just go and put your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872638/make-the-link-visible/49873412#49873412 ?