# Make the link visible

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties here trying to put the link there to work. I cant get the link to appear. I put there the link for the paragraph that i want to be a link, but it is not working. I believe the hover effect is somehow affecting the link, but am not being able to see which and what part.

Edit 1: I want the red box to appear in front of everything, and after hovering it, the red box disappears, and the link is available

```css
.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.hover:hover::before {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="hover ">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250?text=IMAGEE" class="img-responsive " alt="Image">

  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p class="textoColunas"> <a href="www.google.com">Testes de Diagnóstico e
Entrevistas Vocacionais para admissão
aos cursos que a seguir se indica: 
</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/joseafonso123az/mf7jvry4/7/

Comment: The problem is when you hover the pseudo-element is above the link.. because of `z-index:2;` and the link is only `z-index:1;`.. Just set the `z-index` of the link higher than the pseudo-element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `pointer-events: none`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)</sup> to the overlay:

```css
.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.hover:hover::before {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="hover ">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250?text=IMAGEE" class="img-responsive " alt="Image">

  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p class="textoColunas"> <a href="www.google.com">Testes de Diagnóstico e
Entrevistas Vocacionais para admissão
aos cursos que a seguir se indica: 
</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Despite the snippet not running as expected, this did the trick! thanks

Comment: @JoseAfonso because your are missing the bootstrap include, it's fixed now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it working the way you want it now, by putting this on css:

```
 .hover:hover::before {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index:1;
}
```

[Check it out :)](https://jsfiddle.net/mf7jvry4/48/)

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be changing `z-index` in below:

```
.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2; /* Change the value of this and your code will work */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: This will make the text upfront from the beggining and thats not what I want

Answer (score -1):

You probably didn't include the bootstrap CSS file.

```css
.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.hover * {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class=" col-sm-4 hover ">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250?text=IMAGEE" class="img-responsive " alt="Image">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p class="textoColunas"> <a href="www.google.com">Testes de Diagnóstico e
Entrevistas Vocacionais para admissão
aos cursos que a seguir se indica: 
</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this I lose the hovering part, so no its not what I want